# why c++ insert a junk to array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote a function to insert an element by index into an array and this is the function:

```cpp
bool insertByindex(int array[], int size, int index, int element) {
  if (index > size || index < 0) {
    cout <<"Invalid position!";
    return false;
  } else {
    for (int i = size; i > index; i--) {
      array[i] = array[i - 1];
    }
    array[index]= element;
    return true;
  }
}

int main() {
  int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 5};
  int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    
  // calling the function
  insertByindex(arr, size, 3, 4);

  // print the array
  cout << size << "--> ";
  for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
     cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << "\n";

  // calling the function again
  insertByindex(arr, size, 4, 7);

  // print the array
  cout << size << "--> ";
  for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
        cout << arr[i]<< " ";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It works fine the first time but on the second time, it inserts a junk element on the end and increases the array's size. Why does this happens? This is the output (the first number is array's size and the numbers after ----> is the array's items):

```
5--> 1 2 3 4 5 
7--> 1 2 3 4 7 5 5
```

Why the array's size is 7 (not 6) on the second time and what is that 5 at the end?

Comment: `int i=size` and `array[i]` accesses `array` out of bounds. `arr` has 4 elements, `arr[4]` doesn't exists. `insertByindex(arr,size,4` - you can't insert at element with index 4 (ie. the 5th element). `arr` has 4 elements. Also I do not follow how `size` could have increased - I get always in the output `4-->`. `size` is always `4`.

Comment: @KamilCuk why it worked on first time? and how can i fix this problem?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour because of accssing beyond the array. That explains any behvaviour you observe. Including the misleading worng impressoin that "it workd on first time".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the culprit:

```
for(int i=size; i>index;i--){
            array[i]=array[i-1];
```

At first iteration `i` is the size of the array, so you assign past end of the array!

It invokes Undefined Behaviour and bad things start to occur... Here the implementation has probably put the `size` variable just after the array and you have overwritten it.

Always control twice that no out of bound access occur on an array...

---

As the higher index for an array o size `size` is `size - 1` just write:

```
for(int i=size-1; i>index;i--){
            array[i]=array[i-1];
...
```

And the function should control that `index` is **stricly** less than `size`:

```
if(index >= size || index < 0){
    cout <<"Invalid position!";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I fix that?

Comment: @Roxana: Just start at `size - 1` (see my edit)

Comment: i did that and here is the result : `4--> 1 2 3 4  
7--> 1 2 3 4 7 5 4` i want to shift all element after index forward to make space for new element and to be like `5--> 1 2 3 4 5 
6--> 1 2 3 4 7 5 `

Comment: @Roxana: Please stop writing *past end of array*. For an array of size 4, any access to `array[4]` is UB. But you are right on one point I had not identified the other error... Anyway, `insertByindex(arr,size,4,7);` is **wrong**: `arr[4]` is past end of array.

Answer (score 1):

So your program is showing ***Undefined behavior!!*** This happens when you try to access the memory out of range of the allocated stack (means the memory allocated before the programs start).
In most cases, the compiler will trigger a breaking point to read the undefined memory. But you were lucky that you have accessed the memory block of `size` so when you tried to so the second entry.
So then the `size = 7`, so it read a number ahead of it.
It looks like you would need a memory block that could be expandable. A better way is to heap allocate the memory and when needs to be expanded, can be copied to a new block of memory with more size.
This code should work fine....

```
int* insertByindex(int *array, int size, int index, int element) {
  int *temp = array;
  array = new int[size + 1];

  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    array[i] = temp[i];

  delete[] temp;

  // end of the modification

  if (index > size || index < 0) {
    cout <<"Invalid position!";
    return nullptr;
  } else {
  // Replaced > with >=
    for (int i = size; i >= index; i--) {
      array[i] = array[i - 1];
    }
    array[index]= element;
    return array;
  }
}

int main() {
  int size = 4;
  int *arr = new int[size];
  arr[0] = 1;
  arr[1] = 2;
  arr[2] = 3;
  arr[3] = 5;

  //end of the modification

  // calling the function
  arr = insertByindex(arr, size++, 3, 4);

  // print the array
  cout << 4 << "--> ";
  for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
     cout << arr[i] << " ";
  }
  cout << "\n";

  // calling the function again
  arr = insertByindex(arr, size++, 4, 7);

  // print the array
  cout << size << "--> ";
  for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++) {
        cout << arr[i]<< " ";
  }

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Modified the return statement too. If you want them not altered need to pass in double pointer.

Comment: Please show the head/prototype of your proposed solution function. There is an issue with call-by-value parameters I think.

Comment: I've posted the answer, you can check that out. If any more errors encountered please report them.